# how to implement iAd in ios6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, iad

I'm sorry, but I'm sure this sounds like a stupid question but could someone please walk me through adding iAds into my iOs 6 app. I have seen tutorials out there for iOs 5 and iOs4 but it is all deprecated in iOs6. Sorry, I know this is an awful question, but this seriously is my last resort.

I only have portrait view, so I don't need any code for landscape.

I have the story board all set up for where I want my ad. (at the top).

Thanks! sorry if this has already been asked, but I can't find any answers or questions asked even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the developer page there are a ton of resources.  Hope this helps.

https://developer.apple.com/iad/resources/